# Tables with editable cell in django

Tags: django

How can I make a table view with input boxes and after adding all rows finally save the data together in django. I am using bootstrap table in HTML and dict object is renter on request. I want to build a form with editable table having multiple rows.

Comment: i think a duplicate question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037532/creating-editable-html-tables-with-django

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating editable HTML tables with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037532/creating-editable-html-tables-with-django)